# cakephp use controllers in components

Tags: cakephp, components

I am trying to use a common function to check if a user has already created an account. The following code works in controller level. But i have to copy the same code to all other controllers. So i planned to create a component and put the common function there.

```
public function is_user_has_account() {
  $has_account = $this->Account->find('all', array(
      'fields'=>array('id'), 
      'conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')), 'limit' => 1));
  if($has_account) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

When i put the code in my custom component it did not work. What it the best way to use controller functions in components?  I am using cakephp 1.3

Thank you

Comment: `it did not work` - in what way?

Answer (score 1):

I think moving this functionality to a component is overkill (plus you can simplify the code quite a bit). Instead, I would either move it to your `Account` model:

```
public function is_user_has_account($userID) {
    return $this->hasAny(array('user_id' => $userID));
}
```

or your `AppController`:

```
public function is_user_has_account() {
    return $this->Account->hasAny(array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
}
```